# Move posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I moved my whole wordpress installation on my server from a folder called wordpress to a different place. Now, when I click on a post, the link still contains /wordpress.

I already replaced the url in the `guid` column in the table `wp_posts`.

What else can be the problem?

Comment: I am assuming you changed all relevant options in `wp_options` as well. If not, that is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have changed the installation path in the settings (wp-admin).
If all the links populated by wordpress are wrong it might be an issue with your settings? You cam verify this by creating a new post and check if the link is incorrect there as well.

Just go to Settings->General

Comment: thanks a lot, this is it. I will accept your answer when its possible